# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - jQuery Smooth Div Scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, smooth-scrolling

I think I've got some kind of issue with conflicting jQuery libraries in my wordpress site.. although nothing I can see is really giving me any helping hand to identify exactly what needs changing.

I'm calling jQuery UI and the file in the footer:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js"></script>
```

And adding this below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#online-scroller").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: "always",
    autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight",
    autoScrollingStep: 1,
    autoScrollingInterval: 15 
  });
  $("#online-scroller").bind("mouseover", function () {
    $("#online-scroller").smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
  });
  $("#online-scroller").bind("mouseout", function () {
    $("#online-scroller").smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
  });
});
```

But no matter what combination of $ or jQuery I try to do, I keep getting this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

At the moment, this error is being called in the smoothdivscroll JS file at line 10. Get the file at http://smoothdivscroll.com/download.html

Thomas, if you're reading this, please help?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually loading the jQuery library. You are loading jQueryUI and your smoothdivscroll. You need to import the actual library. See [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Comment: Have added that just above the jquery-ui line in the footer.. and nothing seems to have changed. But I think WP is also loading an older version of the one I've just included.. located in wp-includes.

Comment: If it's the fact that there's $ appearing in the JS File, I don't need to go through the entire file and replace everyone with jQuery do I? Surely not...?